# It seems android BillingClient version 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.1.0 changed behavior and returns cancelled subscriptions

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-services, android-inapp-purchase

I had subscriptions working for 6 month and now it does not work properly.

The problem is that call like `billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync` now returns cancelled subscription purchases.

If I use purchaseToken from such purchase on a server with `Purchases.Subscriptions.Get` then I get JSON that has `"cancelReason": 1,` but purchase object returned by `billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync` inside app does not have `cancelReason` property in its JSON.

How do I learn if purchase is cancelled without relying on my server code?